# r - Find String in Any Elements of a List and Then Use the Name of That List Element

Tags: r, list, for-loop, dplyr

I am trying see if the string exists in any of the elements in a list and then use the name of that list if it does exist.

Right now, I am using `case_when` and `grepl`, but I'd like a more efficient way to look through my `named_list` and then use the name.

```
fruit <- c("apple", "banana", "pear")
drinks <- c("beer", "wine", "coffee")
stuff <- c("chair", "couch", "desk")


df <- data.frame(foo = sample(x = c(fruit, drinks, stuff), size = 10, replace = T),
                 x = sample(1:500, size = 10, replace = T))

df

# foo    x
# pear   449
# wine   241
# pear   53
# couch  72
# banana 443
# coffee 172
# desk   126
# desk   183
# desk   7
# banana 73

df %>%
  mutate(category = case_when(grepl(paste0(fruit, collapse = "|"), foo, ignore.case = T) ~ "fruit",
                              grepl(paste0(drinks, collapse = "|"), foo, ignore.case = T) ~ "drinks",
                              grepl(paste0(stuff, collapse = "|"), foo, ignore.case = T) ~ "stuff"))

# foo    x   category
# pear   449 fruit
# wine   241 drinks
# pear   53  fruit
# couch  172 stuff
# banana 443 fruit
# coffee 172 drinks
# desk   126 stuff
# desk   183 stuff
# desk   7   stuff
# banana 73  fruit

# create named list of lists/vectors
named_list <- Hmisc::llist(fruit, drinks, stuff)
named_list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
gsub("\\d", "", names(sort(unlist(lapply(named_list, lapply, function(x) grep(x, df$foo))))))
#> [1] "drinks" "stuff"  "fruit"  "drinks" "stuff"  "stuff"  "stuff"  "stuff"  "drinks"
#> [10] "fruit"
```

This works by taking the named list and examining each of its vectors (with an lapply). For each vector, it calls lapply again to `grep` each member of the named list's vector against df$foo.

The result is a nested list, where each leaf is a vector of the indices of matches against a particular item. When you unlist this nested list, the names of the named list are associated with each element. These can be arranged in order by their indices, then the names used. You have to strip off numbers that are added to the names by the enclosing gsub.

Comment: That seems to work! But i'm not sure how it's working...can you explain the embedded lapply?

Comment: Sure, I'll update my answer with an explanation @alexb523

Comment: This works with the example, but when I apply it to my actual problem, i am getting the following: Error: Column `category` must be length 77 (the number of rows) or one, not 85. Any idea what's going on? I'm having problems successfully troubleshooting what's going on.

Comment: @alexb523 are you using `dplyr`?

Comment: yes, i am trying to implement it in with `dplyr`. It works when i plug it in the example, but not in my actual code. `df %>% mutate(category = gsub("\\d", "", names(sort(unlist(lapply(named_list, lapply, function(x) grep(x, foo)))))))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution, using the attribute of name

```
tbl <- `names<-`(unlist(lst <- list(fruit = fruit, drinks = drinks, stuff = stuff)),
                 rep(names(lst),lengths(lst)))
df$category <- names(tbl)[match(df$foo,tbl)]
```

**Example**

```
> df
      foo   x category
1    desk 277    stuff
2    beer 362   drinks
3   chair 438    stuff
4   apple 494    fruit
5  banana 330    fruit
6   chair 263    stuff
7  banana 329    fruit
8    pear  79    fruit
9   apple 213    fruit
10   wine  37   drinks
```